# Updating a Google add-on without access to the original Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, add-on

A Google add-on we're publishing needs updating because its installation is failing. However we don't have access to the original Apps Script anymore, but we do have a matching GCP.

I have a repo with the code, so I re-created a new standalone Apps Scrip and tried to add it to the project. I got this error:[Associate a GCP to an Apps Script project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lQUu.png)

1. Is it possible to determine the account from which the script was published/created?
2. How can I update the add-on without having access to the original
   Apps Script? Is there a way to find the file from the GCP settings
   maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [`My executions`](https://script.google.com/home/executions?user_access_level=1.2.3.4) you should be able to see the list of executions that happened in your name. Make sure to select all the `Project access` checkboxes.

If this doesn't show the failed executions, I would try looking into the Cloud logs to try to find the execution failures. [You can see how here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_cloud_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console).

In both cases there should be enough information to know where the script is and who's the owner.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. My executions only show the test scripts I have access too, while I don't see anything in the Cloud logs, it's all empty...

Comment: If you use a GCP project and have a deployed, I assume you are using a Workspace account. I would [contact Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) and ask them help.